# Redirect from a domain without hosting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, hosting, friendly-url

I have 2 domains, the first is old, not hosting assigned and redirects to the new domain, in which a prestashop with friendly urls is installed.

www.olddomain1.com  >>  www.newdomain2.com

The problem is when there are parameters in the old domain and want to redirect the new domain with the friendly url.

www.olddomain1.com/shop/home.php?cat=74  >>  www.newdomain2.com/cat=74

As I can do redirections so that:

www.olddomain1.com/shop/home.php?cat=74  >>  www.newdomain2.com/pillows

That way I can set this up? Is there any way that is not hosting the old assign a domain?

Comment: Off-topic and unclear what you're asking. Questions about Apache HTTPd redirects and .htaccess are best asked on ServerFault. Please include any configuration you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to configure DNS `CNAME` record for `www.olddomain1.com` that is pointing to `www.newdomain2.com`. That way all requests for `www.olddomain1.com` will go to your new web server.

Next, you need to configure your new webserver to respond to requests that have `Host: www.olddomain1.com` header.

If above two steps are done, all you need is mod_rewrite rule, but you need to provide exact and precise explanation what is being rewritten to. if all you need is `www.olddomain1.com/shop/home.php?cat=74 >> www.newdomain2.com/cat=74`, then this should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.olddomain1.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=(.+)
RewriteRule shop/home.php http://www.newdomain2.com/cat=%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It was not exactly what I needed but with some modification this works perfectly.